# Enforce a sequence for calling methods in a class

Tags: python

Lets say we want to implement a functionality using a class

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def generate_query(self):
        # Generate the query
        pass

    def send_query(self):
        # send the query over the network
        pass

    def receive_response(self):
        # read the response from buffer
        pass
```

What's the best way to make sure that `generate_query()` has been called before `send_query()`, ofcourse vice versa doesn't make sense. It's important because simply mentioning in the API documentation to call another method before you've called `send_query()` is another thing, but checking it explicitly in the code in `send_query()` that `generate_query()` has been called before is a good practice IMO.

I am expecting a solution like if `generate_query()` has not been called, we raise an exception or so.

There was a nice pythonic way to do this, I had read somewhere, but I forgot the source and the solution both.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: You can't just call it from `__init__`?

Comment: I am nowhere gonna make a call, assume that this a module and shall be used by another programmer(you don't even know who!), how do I make sure that he uses the methods in the right sequence, simply calling receive_response first would raise an exception

Comment: If you include the call to `generate_query` in the `__init__` it will be called every time you create a new instance of your class. So like @Klaus D. said - the call will be guaranteed.

Comment: In short, you can only see if the query is generated or not by checking the existence/non-emptiness of query. Because __calling `generate_query()` need not always generate one__. The query generation tried could be erroneous in which case, a well designed `generate` function will throw an exception leaving the query __not__ generated. Also, you are not enforcing any restriction on when the query should be generated. __Your condition should be the existence of the query rather than the attempt to generate it.__

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with a base class you can inherit from to enforce method call order (tested in Python 2.7 and 3.6):

```
from types import FunctionType, MethodType

class Sequenced(object):

    def __init__(self):
        _methods = [name for name, obj in self.__class__.__dict__.items()
            if type(obj) == FunctionType]
        assert set(self._method_sequence).issubset(set(_methods))
        self._sequence_pos = 0

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        attr = object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        if type(attr) == MethodType:
            if attr.__name__ in self._method_sequence:
                if self._sequence_pos >= len(self._method_sequence):
                    raise RuntimeError("All sequenced methods already called.")
                if attr.__name__ != self._method_sequence[self._sequence_pos]:
                    raise RuntimeError("{0} method call expected.".format(
                        self._method_sequence[self._sequence_pos]))
                self._sequence_pos += 1
            def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                return attr(*args, **kwargs)
            return func_wrapper
        else:
            return attr
```

Be warned, I don't fully understand how this works (I've managed to stop `__getattribute__` from causing infinite recursion, but I don't understand what caused it in the first place, and I don't understand why I have to use `FunctionType` in one place and `MethodType` in another). It passed my minimal testing (Python 2.7 and 3.6), but you'll want to make sure you test it as well.

All you need to do with your class is make it inherit from `Sequenced`, and modify its `__init__` method like so:

```
class MyClass(Sequenced):

    def __init__(self):
        self._method_sequence = [
            "generate_query",
            "send_query",
            "receive_response"
        ]
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()

    def generate_query(self):
        # Generate the query
        pass

    def send_query(self):
        # send the query over the network
        pass

    def receive_response(self):
        # read the response from buffer
        pass
```

The base class allows your class to contain other methods (sequencing is only enforced on methods within the `_method_sequence` list). `_method_sequence` can contain duplicates if you want methods to be called more than once.

In the case of a sequenced method being called out of sequence, or attempting to use a sequenced method after already having gone through the list, `RuntimeError` is raised.

It's possible to modify the base class so that sequence methods can be called repeatedly once available, but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

My idea would be to keep a instance variable name flag which will be True,if the generate_query is called, and if flag is false, it means that generate_query is not called and so, you will call the generate_query inside send_query or show a message.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to use boolean flags. This approach is simple, but not very clean.

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.generated = False

    def generate_query(self):
        self.generated = True

        # Generate query

    def send_query(self):
        if not self.generated:
            self.generate_query()

        # Send query

    def receive_response(self):
        pass
```

I would advice you to try to reconstruct the class and methods. Requiring methods to run in a particular order is prone for errors, especially if it is not documented.

Comment: Even if it is documented, as a module writer, I should code the class in a way that it raises exception if `send_query` has been called before `generate_query`, isn't it like calling `socket.connect()` before calling `socket.socket()`, don't take the full analogy though!

Comment: Yes @sinister, that makes it a lot easier for everyone else. However, in languages that have private accessors, like Java, then you can to a better degree hide dependent methods on each other. Because everything is public in Python it may make things more prone for errors.